# ICU and basic opreation on UTF-8 strings

Tags: c, string, icu

how can I do basic string operations such as strcat, strlen and ... on UTF-8 string with ICU library in C.

I found lots of functions for UTF-16 but not for UFT-8.

Answer (score 0):

ICU supplies a set of C macros and functions for working with UTF-8 encoded strings. Start here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/utf-8

Comment: Yes, I know, I have seen this page, but the point is, I couldn't find strlen and other functions. where can i find a complete list of UTF-8 based functions?

Comment: You want bytes length or count of characters? Either way, you need to first deal with normalization or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular `strcat` and similar functions with UTF-8.  As for length, if you mean to count characters you can do `mbstowcs(NULL, s, 0)`.

Comment: mbstowcs if  for converting other encodings such as ANSI to wide char. not for getting length of string. it only return the required space for creating new UTF-16 string.

Comment: @user335870: Have you tried the code I wrote before saying it doesn't work?